# windows Task scheduler - making a task run as an application rather than background process

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-11

I have a windows `powershell` script that runs all, day every. It's started by `task manager` at 5 minutes past midnight every morning, runs as an application (i.e. in a `powershell` console on my desktop) and then shuts itself down at about 5 minutes to midnight every night.

Running as an application has a number of advantages. I can very easily see that it's running, I can easily see that it's working (continuous messages scrolling up the screen) and I can force it to an orderly shutdown by pressing `ctrl+c` any time.

The windows task that initiates this is configured as `run only when user is logged on` this is OK 99% of the time because my account is always logged on. This option means that the task is always run as an application on my desktop.

Occasionally a power failure or update will cause a re-boot (logging my account off). I want my powershell task to re-start so I added a second trigger to the task 'at system startup'. Experimentation shows that this will *only* work if the option `run only when user is logged on` is changed to `run whether user is logged on or not`. However this option has a catch, the powershell process now appears in task manager as a `background process`, not an `app`. So now I don't have the script running in a window on my screen, I can't monitor it's progress nor can I shut it down cleanly (`task manager` followed by `End Task` is my only option)

I'd like task manager to always run my script as an app not a background process, so I want to either

1. configure task manager so that on re-boot my account is logged-on and the script started as an app, OR
2. configure task manager so that IF my account is logged-on then the script is started as an app and if my account is not-logged on (i.e. after a power failure) then (and only then) is it started as a background process.

Or is there another solution? basically I need the script running all the time, and I need to be able to see it running in a window on my desktop so I can see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, think I've found an answer myself.

Instead of one task with two different triggers I've created two different versions of the same task each with a different trigger.

- One is set to run every morning at 5 minutes past midnight and is set
  to `run only when user is logged on`. This takes care of 99% of
  normal operations - the task runs as a fore-ground application in a
  window on my desktop.
- The other is is set to `run at system startup`, this is set to `run whether user is logged on or not` This takes care of the very odd
  occurrence when the job needs to start after an unscheduled outage.
  Ok, it runs as a background process, which as annoying but at least
  it's running!

Comment: Make sure that second task checks whether you have rebooted recently! The way you describe it here makes it sound like you're setting up a reboot loop for yourself (reboot > on startup > reboot). One example way to do this as a powershell command is: `if ((Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem).lastbootuptime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-1)) {Restart-Computer}`